# Google calendar API > Edit Recurring Events > this and following option > persist exceptions

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I created a recurring series using Google-calendar-api from December 11 to December 20. I made a change (For eg: Description) of a single instance on December 18th using "this event" only option.

Then I'm editing the title on December 15 and choosing "This and following" options. This resets my exception on December 18th (where the description was changed) to match the December 15th description.

How to persist the exceptions of the series when splitting the parent series into two for 'this and following' as mentioned in the Google API docs.

Edit:
To create Google recurring event:

```
$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event([
           'summary'  => $meeting->title,
           'location' => $meeting->location,
           'start' => [
                'date'     => $all_day_startdate,
                'dateTime' => $start_date_time,
                'timeZone' => $timezone
           ],
           'end' => [
               'date'     => $all_day_enddate,
               'dateTime' => $end_date_time,
               'timeZone' => $timezone
           ],
            'conferenceData' => $conference_link,
        ]);

         $event>setRecurrence(array(format_recurrence_rule_for_google($recurrence_pattern)));

        // set Google calendar event parameters.
        $calendar_id = 'primary';
        $opt_params  = [
            'sendNotifications'     => $send_invite,
            'conferenceDataVersion' => 1
        ];

        
        // create the Google calendar event
        $event = $service->events->insert($calendar_id, $event, $opt_params);
```

To update a single instance:

```
$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event([
            'summary'  => $meeting->title,
            'location' => $meeting->location,
            'start' => [
                   'date'     => $all_day_startdate,
                   'dateTime' => $start_date_time,
                   'timeZone' => $meet_creator->timezone
             ],
             'end' => [
                   'date'     => $all_day_enddate,
                   'dateTime' => $end_date_time,
                   'timeZone' => $meet_creator->timezone
             ],
             "recurringEventId" => $recurring_event_id,
             "originalStartTime" => [
                    "dateTime" => $exist_event->getOriginalStartTime()->getDateTime(),
                        "timeZone" => $meet_creator->timezone
              ],
              "iCalUID" => $exist_event->getiCalUID(),
            
             'conferenceData' => event_conference($meeting->conference)
            ]);

            $opt_params  = [
                    'conferenceDataVersion' => ($generate_conf || $cancel_conf) ? 1 : 0
                ];

            $calendar_id  = 'primary';
            $updatedEvent = $service->events->insert($calendar_id, $event, $opt_params);
```

This and following events code snippet

```
$current_event = $this->get_instance_with_event_id($parent_meeting);
$rec           = format_recurrence_rule_for_google($parent_meeting->meeting_options->recurrence);

$current_event->setRecurrence(array($rec));

// trim the parent recurring event into two
$service->events->update('primary', $parent_meeting->meeting_options->recurring_event_id, $current_event);

              
 $event = $this->create_initial_calendar_event() // which is the first snippet to create recurring event
```

Comment: Please can you post the code which created the event, as well as the code which changed the event?

Comment: Why are you using the insert endpoint to update an instance rather than [update](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/update)?

Comment: Initially I used update endpoint. Then I followed this stackOverflow answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/62597402/11527200) thinking that it will solve my problem but didn't.

And also I followed the insert(Post) request as mentioned in the Google support page: [https://support.google.com/code/answer/64266?hl=en]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short Answer

*It is not possible*

### Explanation

The official documentation explains how to work with [Recurring Events](https://developers.google.com/calendar/recurringevents). It has a section that shows how to *modify all following instances* but following these steps you get two separated `Recurring Events` and the `exception instances` will disappear. There is only one way of modifying some parameters of an `instance` and apply them to *this and following events* and that is using the web version of the `Calendar` (it also respects the exceptions).

### Workarounds

1. **Looping**

   - Loop through all the [instances](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/instances) and [update](https://developers.google.com/calendar/recurringevents#modifying_or_deleting_instances) only those you want. You can set a condition to apply the update only if a propriety  (`start`,`description`) matches with your specification.
   - Disadvantage: one call per update.
2. **Update and Insert** (check the official documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/recurringevents#modifying_all_following_instances))

   - [Events: update](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/update) to trim the event and (re)define the instances that are not going to change. The body request is an [Event resource](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource) that needs all the properties that have been used to create the original `Recurring Event` with the `recurrence` modified to cover the desired days.
   - [Events: insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) to insert the remaining instances with the modified properties. The body request has to be defined with all its properties as in the previous step.
   - Disadvantages: it creates two different `Recurring Events` and the `Event resources` had to be defined from zero. It also overlaps the exceptions.
3. **Get, Patch and Insert** (can handle some exceptions)

   - [Events: get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/get) to get the `Recurring Event` with all its information.
   - [Events: patch](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/patch) to trim the event and keep the `instances` that have the `exceptions`. The body request is an [Event resource](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource) that can be the defined in two ways:

     - From zero: it only needs `start`, `end` and `recurrence`. Using `patch` maintains all the other parameters.
     - From the original event obtained previously with `get`. In your case, you need to modify `start.dateTime` and `end.dateTime` to December 15 (and corresponding hours) and the new parameter that you want to change, for example the `description`.
   - [Events: insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) to insert the remaining instances without `exceptions`. The `Event resource` used in this step is a clone from the original `Recurring Event`. There are some properties that need to change: `iCalUID = ""`, `id = ""`, and for your case the `recurrence` in order to stop on December 15.
   - Disadvantages: it creates two different `Recurring Events` and takes three different API calls. The `exceptions` are only maintained in one `Recurring Event`.
4. **Cancel instance, insert new event**

   - [Events: instances](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/instances) to get the `instances` of a `Recurring Event`.
   - [Cancel an instance](https://developers.google.com/calendar/recurringevents#modifying_or_deleting_instances) of a `Recurring Event` changing its `status`: *Cancelled exceptions of an uncancelled recurring Event indicate that this instance should no longer be presented to the user.*
   - [Events: insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) to insert a new `Event resource` on the same date as the `cancelled instance` so that future changes to the `Recurring Event` do not change this `exception`. The properties can be obtained from the original `instance`.
   - Disadvantage: The exception event does not belong to the `Recurring Event`.

### References

- [Recurring Events](https://developers.google.com/calendar/recurringevents)
- [Event resource](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource)
- [Events: instances](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/instances)
- [Events: update](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/update)
- [Events: insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert)
- [Events: get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/get)
- [Events: patch](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/patch)
- [Modify/cancel instances](https://developers.google.com/calendar/recurringevents#modifying_or_deleting_instances)